# Powershell. Не работает метод .trim() для строки внутри параметра -Filter коммандлета Get-ADUser

Tags: строки, методы, powershell

Объясните пожалуйста, почему если я передаю переменную типа String в фильтр командлета допустим Get-ADUser, например:

```
$string = "username "
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $string}
```

То всё нормально отрабатывет.

Однако, если в теле фильтра я применяю к строке метод .trim(), то PowerShell говорит что нет такого метода у строчки и работать отказывается, пример:

```
$string = "username "
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $string.trim()}
```

Я проверил: тип объекта при использовании метода trim() возвращаеnся такой же, как и был у оригинальной строки.
Разумеется можно завести промежуточную переменную, которой присвоить строку без пробелов обработанную методом .trim()

Мне интересно почему я не могу применять методы внутри параметров коммандлета.
Нужно/можно ли как-то дополнительно экранировать вызов метода при использовании внутри параметров коммандлета?

UPD. Похоже AD-коммадлеты просто так работают, судя по документации:
"
The Filter parameter translates PowerShell-like expressions to an LDAP filter, but doesn't support just any arbitrary PowerShell statement, only a specific set of comparison operations with attribute names as the left-hand operand and the comparison value on the right hand side.
"
Поэтому есдинственный выход, готовить строку для фильтра предварительно.

Comment: `trim())` - не лишняя скобка написана? Либо наоборот не дописана скобка в начале переменной `($string.trim())`

Comment: ну и для решения проблемы я бы обрабатывал сразу переменную `$string = ("username ").Trim()`

Comment: Да, скобка лишняя, спасибо.(сейчас поправлю вопрос) Но её наличие/отсутсвие на результат не влияет.

Comment: Согласен что лучше подавать обработанный вариант. Но было бы удобно иметь возможность убирать лишние пробелы, допустим когда я получаю исходные данные из массива, а массив формирую из буфера обмена через Get-Clipboard. Хотелось бы понять, можно ли вообще так делать или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Contents
> about_ActiveDirectory_Filter 2
>
> about_ActiveDirectory_Filter TOPIC Active Directory Filter
>
> SHORT DESCRIPTION Describes the syntax and behavior of the search
> filter supported by the Active Directory module for Windows
> PowerShell.
>
> LONG DESCRIPTION Most get-AD* Active Directory module cmdlets use the
> Filter parameter to search for objects. The Filter parameter has been
> implemented to replace the function of the LDAP Filter and adds
> support for Windows PowerShell variables, rich data types, improved
> error checking and an Active Directory extended form of the Windows
> PowerShell Expression Language.
>
> For more information about the Windows PowerShell Expression Language
> syntax, see about_Regular_Expressions.

```
$string = "username "

#Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $string.trim()}
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$($string.trim())'"
```

в параметр -Filter подается строка синтаксиса какого то "Windows PowerShell Expression Language", похоже её нужно собрать до подачи в параметр.

Comment: Да, похоже это касается для параметра -Filter всех коммандлетов, по крайней мере для модуля Active Directory. Хотя, если для какой другой задачи достаточно будет поиска по параметру -Identity, вместо Filter - то там можно строку прям внутри запроса собрать. Благодарю!